# Oracle BI Publisher Scheduled Report to FTP File Name

Tags: obiee, oracle-bi

I have created report in Obiee Publisher for customer sales invoices that will be deliver to FTP Server for review by user. no my requirement is report name should be based on column value.

please assist how to generate dynamic report name based on Custom column value in oracle bi publihser 11g.

i tried to place column name "customer_name" but generated report has not fetched customer name from data model.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.